# How to render a template containing CSS with }} sequence inside using Twig

Tags: css, templates, twig

The sequence `}}` within the CSS fragment is parsed as a Twig *delimiter*.

```
<style>
    @media (touch-enabled),
    (-webkit-touch-enabled),
    (-moz-touch-enabled),
    (-o-touch-enabled),
    (-ms-touch-enabled),
    (modernizr){#touch{top:9px;position:absolute}}
</style>
```

What should I do to overcome that ?

Comment: What kind of CSS could contain `}}`? Can you replace that with `} }`?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: Have made an edit to provide some sample. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I repeat, wouldn't some whitespace fix that (apart from the fact that your lack of newlines reduces the readability)?

Comment: @JanDvorak CSS media queries can have those brackets.

Comment: @Licson I agree; however, I'd expect them to be separated by a newline. I was wondering if there was a case where whitespace cannot be added.

Comment: Added the whitespace as suggested but it still sucks. The twig lexer reports: `Unclosed comment in "layout.twig" at line 208`.

Comment: @menjaraz try adding a new line instead. Also there's a question: why can't you add indention to your code?

Comment: Yes, "beautifying" the code doesn't harm but the thing is that the twig lexer stumbles at the `}}`,  `}<space>}` or `}<nl>}`. The same old tune.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delved into the docs and finally find a decent solution:

```
{% raw %}(modernizr){#touch{top:9px;position:absolute}}{% endraw %}
```

Doing so makes the Twig lexer "happy" and the issue with my template is over once and for all.